# How can i solve this loading failed package of 'Devtools"?

Tags: r, installation, package, devtools, install.packages

I tried to install the devtools package but it still doesn't work properly it always throws an error, I have tried to uninstall and reinstall the application but it can't work either.

here is my code

During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) :
unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R-4.3.1/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
[Workspace loaded from ~/.RData]

> library(devtools)
> Loading required package: usethis
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘usethis’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
> unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R-4.3.1/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
> LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Error: package ‘usethis’ could not be loaded

Restarting R session...

During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) :
unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R-4.3.1/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

> install.packages("usethis")
> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/usethis_2.2.2.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 896806 bytes (875 KB)
> downloaded 875 KB

package ‘usethis’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8ur33s\downloaded_packages

> library(devtools)
> Loading required package: usethis
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘usethis’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
> unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R-4.3.1/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
> LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Error: package ‘usethis’ could not be loaded

> remove.packages("devtools")
> Removing package from ‘C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> install.packages( "devtools",type="win.binary")
> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/devtools_2.4.5.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 435924 bytes (425 KB)
> downloaded 425 KB

package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8ur33s\downloaded_packages

> library(devtools)
> Loading required package: usethis
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘usethis’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
> unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R-4.3.1/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
> LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Error: package ‘usethis’ could not be loaded

> remove.packages("devtools")
> Removing package from ‘C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Restarting R session...

During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) :
unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R-4.3.1/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

> install.packages( "devtools",type="win.binary")
> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/devtools_2.4.5.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 435924 bytes (425 KB)
> downloaded 425 KB

package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWGvduz\downloaded_packages

> library(devtools)
> Loading required package: usethis
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘usethis’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
> unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R-4.3.1/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
> LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Error: package ‘usethis’ could not be loaded

I've tried some of the solution I've found in others but it also still can't. if anyone can assist please.

Comment: Do the following. Shutdown your computer and restart it. Reinstall R again. Install Rtools. Start Rstudio and install usethis and devtools!

Comment: @TarJae i've tried doing this but it still shows me the same error when i tried to load it even when the packages installation was successful

library(devtools)
Loading required package: usethis
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘usethis’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.1/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
Error: package ‘usethis’ could not be loaded